# In Alan Bennet's The History Boys Mrs Lintott says to Irwin 'If I was a better teacher..'. Why does she not say 'if I were a better teacher?

Tags: fiction, characters

I don't understand why Mrs Lintott does not seem to be using the subjunctive

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid that questions about analysing existing works of literature are off-topic here. This question exists in a bit of a grey area; I'm not sure whether it would be better suited to English.SE or Literature.SE. I'd recommend checking their respective on-topic guidelines, and then making that judgement call yourself.

Comment: This question would be closed as a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/660/191178 on English SE.